# sendRedirect JSP

Tags: jsp

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de chat para probar el application.set o get y salgan los usuarios y lo que escriben y todo va bien, pero tengo que hacer un botón para que recargue la página y no soy capaz...

```
   <form action="verchat.jsp" name="fomchat" method="POST">
      <input type="text" name="texto" placeholder="escribe aquí" value="">
      <input type="submit" name="btnchat" value="Enviar">
    </form>

    <textarea  cols=66 rows=12 name="Texto" placeholder="chat" value=""><%=frase%></textarea><br/>

    <input type="button" name="btnrecarga" value="Recargar">
```

También he probado con

```
if(request.getParameter("btnrecarga") != null){
   response.sendRedirect("http://localhost:8080/ChatWeb/verchat.jsp");
}
```

y

```
if(request.getParameter("btnrecarga") != null){
   response.sendRedirect("localhost:8080/ChatWeb/verchat.jsp");
}
```

y

```
if(request.getParameter("btnrecarga") != null){
                  response.sendRedirect("verchat.jsp");
                  return;
}
```

Muchas gracias !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has un `sendRedirect` al **servlet**:

`request.sendRedirect("/chat");`

O usa el dispatcher:

```
request
  .getRequestDispatcher("verchat.jsp")
  .dispatcher.forward(request,response);
```